# Show reflexivity of Sobolevspace $W^{1,4}(0,1)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I would like to show elementary - using the canonical embedding - that the Sobolevspace $W^{1,4}(0,1)$ is reflexive.

Therefore I set $X=W^{1,4}(0,1)$ and now I have to show that the canonical embedding

$$
i\colon X\to X'', i(x)(x')=x'(x)
$$

is bijective and isometric.

---

I think the canonical embedding is **always** injective and isometric. So I only have to show here, that it is surjective.

Am I right?

How can I show that?

Let $x''$ be in $X''$. Now I have to find a $x\in X$ with $i(x)=x''$, right?

But - how?

Greetings

Comment: I have removed the tag ([tag:reflexive]). According to the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reflexive/info), this tag is for questions about reflexive relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [Clarkson's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson%27s_inequalities) to see that $L^p(\Omega)$ is reflexive for any $p\in (1,\infty)$. So is $(L^p(\Omega))^{N+1}$.
2. Show that $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is a closed subset of $(L^p(\Omega))^{N+1}$. We can use sequential closeness.
3. Use the non-trivial fact that a closed subspace of a reflexive space is reflexive.

Comment: 1. und 3. are okay. I can use that. But i did not come along  with 2. How can I show that it is a closed subset?

Comment: I think it is better to use the space $(L^p)^{N+1}$ instead of $L^p$

Comment: @Tomás Right, $L^p$ alone looks misleading.

Comment: Why $(L^p(\Omega))^{N+1}$? And how can i show that it is closed subset?

Comment: @math12, there is a natural isometry between $W^{1,p}$ and subspace $(L^P(\Omega))^{N+1}$. Try to find it by yourself first.

Comment: Since uniform convexity is a condition on all 2-dimensional subspaces, it passes to closed subspaces. Hence the Milman-Pettis theorem already used in 1 can be applied again --- although Milman-Pettis (combined with Clarkson's inequality) is probably way harder than the non-trivial fact in 3.